# How open file based on extension?

Tags: python, file

I want to open *any* .txt file in the same directory.

In ruby I can do

```
File.open("*.txt").each do |line|
       puts line
end
```

In python I can't do this it will give an error

```
file = open("*.txt","r")
print(file.read())
file.close()
```

It gives an error invalid argument.

So is there any way around it?

Comment: You would have to find all files that end with .txt in that directory, and then have a for loop that reads the file. Here is a way to grab only files with certain extensions in a directory: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python

Comment: You'll have to do it yourself. Take a look at os.listdir()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can directly use the `glob` module for this

```
import glob
for file in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        print(f.read())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) to list all files in the current directory.

```
all_files = os.listdir()
```

Then, filter the ones which have the extension you are looking for and open each one of them in a loop.

```
for filename in all_files:
    if filename.lower().endswith('.txt'):
        with open(filename, 'rt') as f:
            f.read()
```

Comment: Thanks, i used this way before but i found it bit inefficient

Comment: @yippiez Inefficient as spends too much CPU, too much memory, or too much of your time as a developer? If it is the last one, well, create a function which you will always call ;)